keep selected option visible in dropdown after submitting
I am using the following script to retrieve data from my mysql db and to fill a dropdown. Retrieving, selecting and submitting are working perfectly. The only thing is that the selected option falls back to the initial option value of the values retrieved. I want the selected value to remain visible until the user changes the selection. I checked several scripts in Stack but could not reach at a solution. Obviously I am missing something in the script  but 'what'? Is there anyone that can help me out?
<!-- fetches values from the database -->
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT provincie FROM col_erfgoed";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $option = "";
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $provincie = $row['provincie'];
            $option.='<option value="'.$provincie.'">'.$provincie.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    
<!-- lists the options in the database -->
    <h4>Make a choice from the options</h4>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <select name="provincie" id="options" class="options"> 
            <?php echo $option?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>

